# How To Mock Out KafkaProducer Used Inside a Scala Class

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, scalatest

I want to write a unit test for a Scala class.  The purpose of the class is to collect metrics and post them on a Kafka topic.  I am trying to mock the producer in the unit test to ensure sanity of the rest of the code.  Below is a simplified version of my class:

```
class MyEmitter(sparkConf: SparkConf) {
    <snip> -- member variables
    private val kafkaProducer = createProducer()

def createProducer(): Producer[String, MyMetricClass] = {
    val props = new Properties()
    ...
    Code to initialize properties
    ...

    new KafkaProducer[String, MyMetricClass](props)
}

def initEmitter(metricName: String): SomeClass = {
    // Some implementation
}

def collect(key: String, value: String): Unit = {
    // Some implementation
}

def emit(): Unit = {
    val record = new ProducerRecord("<topic name>", "<key>", "<value>")
    kafkaProducer.send(record)
}
```

What I would like to do in my unit test is to mock out the producer and check whether the *send()* command has been called and, if so, whether the producer record matches the expectation.  I have been unsuccessful to find a solution on my own.  Googling the solution has also been unfruitful.  If anyone knows how the problem could be solved, I will be most grateful.

Comment: https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/MockProducer.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'new' is generally an enemy of testing, so you should extract the creation of that object so you can either pass a real KafkaProducer or a mock

One way to do it without changing the interface could be

```
def createProducer(
        producer: Properties => KafkaProducer = props => new KafkaProducer[String, MyMetricClass](props)
        ): Producer[String, MyMetricClass] = {

   val props = new Properties()
   producer(props)
}
```

So then in real code you keep calling

```
myEmmiter.createProducer()
```

But in test you'd do

```
val producerMock = mock[KafkaProducer]    
myEmmiter.createProducer(_ => producerMock)
```

Another good thing about this is that you could also stub the function itself so you can verify that the `props` your method creates are the expected ones

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  It allows me to see what has been passed to the mock producer.

That being said, this works because there already exists a mock Kafka producer.  If there was a different service/class in the code, it means I need to create a mock up of the said class, correct?

Comment: Yes, every time you want to verify an interaction with a 3rd party you need to structure your code in a way that allows replacing said 3rd party by a mock